# How to track down OOM?

Tags: bitcoin-core, lightning-network-daemon, memory, umbrel

Since a while LND on m Bitcoin Node is restarting weekly a I get an OOM:

```
Feb 12 21:07:24 umbrel kernel: node invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x100cca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE), order=0, oom_score_adj=0

Feb 12 21:07:25 umbrel kernel: oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=fd6a4e7d7c051ba13160a8ccbfb06cbc318d6529dab17e259804899aa073d11a,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/,task=lnd,pid=24810,uid=1000
```

How can I find out what is causing the problem?

Many thanks in advance for your help or any hint :-)

Comment: From the logs, it appears you are using Umbrel. This is likely an Umbrel-specific issue related to their custom OS. I'd suggest checking out https://github.com/getumbrel/umbrel and asking for support in their Telegram chat.

Comment: I would recommend not using umbrel as their support is really inconsistent and they are not a totally open-source product

Comment: Thanks @poseidon, well I'm aware of it but not quite ready to switch over yet to something better, was thinking of a an upgrade my RPi4  to Raspibolt or even build a new bare metal node and migrate over :-)

Comment: That's understandable, I personally have not deployed a Lightning Node since my umbrel suffered its series of horrible issues, thankfully I did not lost too many sats in that escapade but I certainly learned that diving into lightning was not super easy and 'safe' especially not opening tons of channels with barely known peers.

Comment: @deekee I setup a LND node recently. If you are even relatively comfortable with Linux command line that should be a breeze for you. Will also teach you the basics of lightning from a developer level. Next to impossible to know why Umbrel would be doing something from my point of view. LND is much easier to debug. Also OOM generally suggests you have many processes running on a low memory device. Increasing the amount of ram can potentially help or closing background applications that arent being used on the device.